# Delphi TIdHTTPProxyServer запросить вместо одного домена другой

Tags: delphi, redirect, proxy, indy

Имеем: `TIdHTTPProxyServer`

Требуется: если `Target` содержит `xxx.com`, запросить и вернуть данные с сайта `yyy.com` (На самом деле просто по IP запросить `xxx.com`)

Чисто HOST махнуть, редирект не катит.

Предположительно делается в `OnHTTPBeforeCommand`. Не могу найти где изменить до самого запроса хост. 
Пробовал по всякому - эффект нулевой

```
procedure TXXX.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPBeforeCommand(AContext:
  TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
begin
  if AContext.Target.Contains('ya.ru') then
    AContext.Headers.CommaText := AContext.Headers.CommaText.Replace('ya.ru', 'u.to');
end;
```

Прошу пару строк кода чтобы просто перенаправить запрос с xxx.com на yyy.com не меняя ничего.
IOHandler подключен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно изменить только хост, то это можно сделать, добавив одну строку:

```
procedure TXXX.OnHTTPBeforeCommand(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
begin
  if AContext.Target.Contains('ya.ru') then begin
    AContext.Headers.CommaText := AContext.Headers.CommaText.Replace('ya.ru', 'u.to');
    TIdTCPClient(AContext.OutboundClient).Host := 'u.to';
  end;
end;
```

Если же вдруг нужно изменить и путь к документу, то тут уже придётся модифицировать код компонента (`TIdHTTPProxyServer` и `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext`) т.к. свойство `AContext.Document` объявлено как "только для чтения".